# Date format and Client-Server interaction

Tags: .net, internationalization

Imagine an abstract problem.

There is a client (`C`) that interacts to a server(`S`). They changes a date variable(`d`).

A server can be French or English, the client too.

A date sent by a French client ("31/12/2011") to an English Server("12/31/2011") can't recognize it. And viceversa.

How to avoid such a problem in .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you in control of both the client and the server? If so, just agree on a format and culture - I'd suggest the invariant culture - and explicitly make sure that both sides adhere to it.

You can very easily parse and format in .NET using the invariant culture - look for `ToString` and `Parse`/`TryParse` overloads which include an `IFormatProvider` parameter.

Comment: say we control both. But what exactly do you mean "both sides adhere to it". As I understood, I store received data from French Client UI in the French format(31/12), transform it in invariant culture(??/??), store it in that culture in the DB, read from DB in that "invariant" culture(??/??), and send it to a English client UI to the local(English) format(12/31)?

Comment: could be that a DB has its own format of dates, that will force fields of type à la "DateTime" be in the installed local culture in the DB?.. say a French SQL Server keep only dates in "dd/mm/yyyy" format or things like this?..

Comment: @serhio: You need to understand the difference between the value in a DateTime variable/column and its textual representation. It's the same as the difference between the value of an integer and its representation in base 10. The number "twenty" is the same value whether I represent it as "20" or "0x14". They're just different ways of communicating the values. You don't "store" the data in the "French format". You store it as a `DateTime`. If you need to display it to a user, you do so by formatting it in their culture. For machine-machine comms, use a culture-invariant format.

Answer (score 1):

Send it between the client and server using the Ticks property. That's a number and will always be the same no matter what you want to format the date as.

Comment: good idea, but even integers could be formatted differently because of thousand separator.

Comment: It'll also be much harder to debug in log files than a culture-invariant date string...

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you are sending the date as string? The best thing would be to share the date using DateTime datatype. If for any reason, you can just send the string, best is to convert the date value to LongDateFormat and then transfer, which could be parsed on the other end to get the meaningful date.